# Windows 10 - Wifi keeps disconnecting and is removing wifi option

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

Related: [windows 10 wifi suddenly disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/1365484/windows-10-wifi-suddenly-disappears)

My wifi (does not matter whether 2.4G or 5G) will randomly disconnect. Not only that, upon disconnecting the wifi option is missing. Clicking the internet button on the taskbar only shows airplane mode, no wifi or mobile hotspot. Note that it *may* not be random at all, it only disconnects when I am using it. That is, Wifi will not disconnect if there are running programs using internet.

More info: Driver is Intel Wifi 6 AX201 160 MHz. Latest version (20.40.0.7) is installed. Error name is code 43. I am very sure the problem is not the internet since my other devices can connect to it without any issues.

Fortunately, I was able to temporarily fix this but the problem keeps persisting. Here are a list of things I tried so far:

1. Updating the driver. When this first happened, the driver version was 20.0.0.6. I manually updated it and the problem was temporarily fixed.
2. Uninstalling the driver (did this twice, one where "Delete the driver software" is ticked) and restarting.
3. Disabling the device and re-enabling it. Again, only a temporary fix.
4. Untick "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" under Properties section. Not sure if this fixed it (temporarily)
5. Restarting Wlan Autoconfig service.

Any ideas why this is happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: Error code 43 means a hardware malfunction. If the device is the wifi adapter, Windows will rightly assume that there is no longer any wifi or internet connection. This might be a hardware problem, so try another external wifi adapter as verification.